# How can I make sphinx-build build faster?

Tags: python-sphinx

The [sphinx-build documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html) says that it only rebuilds changed files. But in this project,  it's rebuilding all the output files for every module. The "highlighing module code" stage takes a particularly long time. The Python source files haven't changed at all, and nor have the .rst files generated by `sphinx-apidoc` - I've only edited some other .rst files.

There are over 700 modules in this project, so it's taking about 20 minutes for `sphinx-build`, even with `-j 8`. How can I make it faster?

The command I'm using is:

```
sphinx-build -M html source build
```

And the relevant part of `source/index.rst`:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   tutorial/index
   library/modules
   development/index
   setup/index
   usage/index
   test_cases/index
   services/index
   troubleshooting
   todo/index

Indices and tables
------------------

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

I'm changing files inside the `services` directory.

Comment: sphinx-apidoc is not a sphinx-build option or builder. Don't equate the two. They are two different apps. That said, it is usual to run `sphinx-apidoc` once, then update the resulting reST files manually as your modules update. This will allow Sphinx to cache previous builds and update only changed files. 20 minutes is an obscenely long time, but for 700 modules (that's a lot), maybe not. Do the 700 modules have their own documentation? If so, then use intersphinx.

Comment: The Makefile runs sphinx-apidoc, but that reports that the source files haven't changed and doesn't regenerate the .rst files for them. They still have their original timestamps.

Comment: You're running [`make_mode`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-m). I don't understand how that invokes `sphinx-apidoc` because it is not a builder. What you say does not make sense to me. Anyway, I suspect there is something else going on, like a `clean`, which deletes all the rendered HTML and Sphinx's cached doctrees. Maybe try just `make html`?

Comment: The only reason `sphinx-apidoc` comes into it is as the thing that wrote the .rst files corresponding to the Python modules. You are quite right that it is not being invoked now. The .rst files it made have not been touched for a few days, nor have the Python sources, and yet `sphinx-build` is regenerating all the HTML files corresponding to them. All I've changed is the hand-written .rst files in the `services` directory.

Comment: Does your make file have a step that does `clean`? If so, delete it.

Comment: I've taken out all the `clean` steps and run `make html`. It's now doing "highlighting module code" on all the modules, same as ever.

Comment: There's not much more anyone can do without a reproducible example at this point. The build in a new Sphinx project won't do what you experience. I suggest creating a new Sphinx project from scratch, then add bits and pieces to it, testing each bit, until you find where it goes sideways.

Comment: Another thought, try running sphinx-build with [`-vvv` or `-v -v -v` option](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-v).

Comment: I never did find a way to do an incremental build, but the thing that was making it slow was using the "sphinx_rtd_theme" theme. Using "alabaster" makes it twenty times faster. I guess it's because sphinx_rtd_theme has a menu with links to every module in the docs for each module.

Comment: Try changing [`navigation_depth` theme option](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html#html-theme-options) from its default of 4 to 2, and `collapse_navigation` to `True`. See note: "Setting collapse_navigation to False and using a high navigation_depth can cause projects with many files and a deep file structure to generate HTML files that are significantly larger in file size and much longer compilation times." Personally I find alabaster to be completely unnavigable.

Comment: Changing `navigation_depth` didn't make much difference, but changing `collapse_navigation` did - down to under three minutes! That's even with the original `navigation_depth` of 4. I've changed the title of the question to be about making `sphinx-build` faster rather than being about incremental builds specifically, so please put your last comment into an answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing [`navigation_depth` theme option](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html#html-theme-options) from its default of 4 to 2, and `collapse_navigation` to `True`. See note:

> Setting collapse_navigation to False and using a high navigation_depth can cause projects with many files and a deep file structure to generate HTML files that are significantly larger in file size and much longer compilation times."

Answer (score 0):

I added the following property to `conf.py`:

```
html_copy_source = False
```

With this property, Sphinx does not copy the source files to the output (by default, it copies the source files to "_sources").

This did not speed up the build but I have an SSD drive. Maybe if you have a regular one, the process is faster because Sphinx has to copy less files.